# Assist with updating multiple rows SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to update multiple Id's at once.
Let me I pool up the data like this:

```
SELECT locname, palnumber, palId 
FROM stocksafetystg
WHERE palnumber IN ('123456', '123457', '123458')
order by palnumber.
```

Then I get these records

```
Locname palnumber palid
1cD1      3030303  121
1cD2      3030303  122
1cD3      3030303  123
```

Now I want to update pal.
Example:

```
update Pal
    SET palnumber = '2222222'
    where palid = '121'
```

But I want to do this for 1000 records at once.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean *at once*?

Comment: Where is the data which is to be used for these 1000 records? Is it in a table somewhere, will you be entering it as text literals, or something else?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you storing numbers as `varchar`?

Answer (score 0):

Using PL/SQL code you can use bulk update and update any number of rows.
Look for bulk processing with bulk collect and forall.